# Python Tabulate Dictionary containing two values per key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using the [Tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) 0.7.7 package to tabulate a dictionary with two values per key.

I have this code.

```
from tabulate import tabulate

d = {"Dave":("13", "Male") , "Sarah":("16", "Female")}

headers = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"]
print(tabulate(d.items(), headers = headers))
```

I want the following table to be produced -

```
Name    Age    Gender
------  -----  ---------
Dave    13     Male
Sarah   16     Female
```

However, the code is the following table -

```
Name    Age
------  ----------------
Dave    ('13', 'Male')
Sarah   ('16', 'Female')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you read [the docs](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate)? They list the required formats, you'll need to convert your current data structure into one of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you flatten the dictionary items, from *(k, (v1, v2))* to *(k, v1, v2)*, you can get the correct format:

```
from tabulate import tabulate   ​
d = {"Dave":("13", "Male") , "Sarah":("16", "Female")}
​
headers = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"]
print(tabulate([(k,) + v for k,v in d.items()], headers = headers))  

Name      Age  Gender
------  -----  --------
Sarah      16  Female
Dave       13  Male
```

Comment: I didn't seem to think of that! Earlier I managed to get as far as `print(tabulate([(k) + v for k,v in d.items()], headers = headers))` but that didn't work. Wow! What does the comma do in the (k,)?

Comment: In python, comma makes tuples, so `(k,)` makes a tuple of length one which you can add to another tuple, `v` in your case. `(k)` is the same as `k`, which is not what you want here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it is possible given the structure of your input data `d`.

Reformatting your data as such (see below) will give the desired result.

`d = {'Name': ['Dave', 'Sarah'], 'Age': [13, 16], 'Gender': ['Male', 'Female']`

Answer (score 0):

I Know it's very late but this solution also works.

```
from tabulate import tabulate 
d = {"Dave":("13", "Male") , "Sarah":("16", "Female")}

headers = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"]
print(tabulate([(i,) +d[i] for i in d], headers = headers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I wanted to tabulate an array of dictionaries but couldn't find it here so I did the logic my self and I'm posting here if someone needs it c:

```
print(tabulate([(x['id'], x['date']) for x in [i for i in post_ar]], headers=["Code", "Date"]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).